# Typescript struggling to create type declaration in a .d.ts file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I used to have all the corresponding types to a file in the same file.

Begin it like

```
type typeA = {foo: number}
...myCode
```

But to make it cleaner I decided to move the declarations to a .d.ts file

Resulting in the following

```
file.tsx
file.d.ts
```

I moved all the types to file.d.ts like this

```
export declare const DataConverted : {
    low: number,
    high: number,
    open: number,
    close: number,
    openTime: number,
    volume: number
  }
  

  export declare const ChartRefPoints : {
   highestVal? : number,
   lowestVal?: number,
   maxTime? : number,
   minTime? : number,
   maxVolume? : number,
   minVolume? : number
  }
```

But i cant import them in file.tsx

```
import {DataConverted, ChartRefPoints} from "file" //cannot find module file or its corresponding file declarations
```

How am i supposed to use this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.d.ts` files are for declarations for JavaScript files/files which don't aren't typed, not for .tsx files.

> But to make it cleaner I decided to move the declarations to a .d.ts file

It's better to keep types close to their code, so you don't have to switch between different files when changing the code.

But if you really want to put the types in a separate file, create a new `.tsx` or `.ts` file with any name, not a `.d.ts` file.

In addition, `export declare const` doesn't define a type. It tells typescript that you have a variable with a specific type. If you want to define a type, do `export type DataConverted  =`